# Finding the multiplicity of a root in a finite field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

How many roots does $\mathbb{F_{16}}$ have in the polynomial $x^4-1$?

What I've done: $x$ is root iff $x^4=1$ iff $x$ has order $4$,$2$ or $1$. However $\mathbb{F_{16}}-\{0\}=\langle \beta \rangle$ (because of the primitive order element) and $\beta$ has order $15$. Therefore the only solution is $x=1$. How do I know the multiplicity of this root?

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
(x-1)^4=x^4-4x^3+6x^2-4x+1=x^4-1
$$
(since $\Bbb F_{16}$ has characteristic $2$), so the root has multiplicity $4$.

Comment: Why does $\mathbb{F_{16}}$ has characteristic $2$?

Comment: @mathie12 Because $16=2^4$, so $\Bbb F_{16}$ must be an extension (_the_ extension) of degree $4$ over $\Bbb F_2$. Alternately, it is finite, so it must have positive characteristic, it's a field, so the characteristic must be prime, and the additive group has order $16$, so by Lagrange's theorem the characteristic (which by definition is the size of the largest cyclic subgroup) must divide $16$.

Answer (score 1):

Over $\Bbb F_2$ we have $a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2$ and $a+b=a-b$, so we have
$$x^4-1=x^4+1=(x^2+1)^2=(x+1)^4=(x-1)^4$$
So $x=1$ has multiplicity $4$.

Comment: Why $\mathbb{F_2}$?